# How to disable jQuery-UI button and disable click on it

Tags: jquery-ui, button, click

I have the following jQuery-UI dialog with 2 buttons:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 400,
        buttons: [
            {
                class: "btnOK",
                click: function () {...
                }
            },
            {
                class: "btnClose",
                click: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        ]
    });
```

I can disable btnOK with:

```
$('.btnOK').attr("disabled", true).addClass("ui-state-disabled");
OR $('.btnOK').button("disabled");
OR $('.btnOK').button( "option", "disabled",true);
```

However this doen't block click on the button.

How I can disable click?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The working ways are:

```
$('.btnOK').button("disable");
OR $('.btnOK').button( "option", "disabled",true);
OR $('.btnOK').attr("disabled", true).addClass("ui-state-disabled");
```

I just have not cleared the history in my browser, so I didn't see the changes.